# How to have a default format in a specific textbox

Tags: vb.net

How to have a default format in a specific textbox.

For example the user input 1191
The result will be 01-19-01

Comment: Can you give more samples of inputs?

Comment: Have you tried the default .NET date control? It's quite unusual to have a regular textbox suddenly represent a date. Your users will not like you for this. Unless the above is not a date. Please add more information regarding what `01-19-01` is.

Comment: Search for masking textbox in .net. Here is an example. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/666932/Using-Masked-TextBox-in-NET

Comment: But this is not a date, It is a trace code, my customer wants me to have that format, if the user input 1191 it will automatically rewrite the inputed data, and it will look like this 1-19-1 but he suggested me again to make it 01-19-01, so the format will always two digits.

Comment: thank you! masking textbox is very helpful.